# Incremental stdout out of fabric

Tags: python, linux, fabric

I'm new to fabric and want to run a long-running script on a remote computer, so far, I have been using something like this:

```
import fabric
c = fabric.Connection("192.168.8.16") # blocking
result = c.run("long-running-script-outputing-state-information-into-stdout.py")
```

Is there a way to read stdout as it comes asynchronously instead of using the 'result' object that can be used only after the command has finished?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you do mean, but normally fabric displays the output of an command that is being executed! If you try to do for example `pip install -r requirements.txt` which will install all required and pre-defined python modules, you will see the whole output!

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is something like `p = subprocess.Popen(["ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`, where the command can run asynchronously and you can read its output from pipe while it's still running.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing.
I am administering a couple of fedora computers in my household. I use the subprocess and concurrent libraries to issue admin commands in paralell over ssh, and
pipe results back as the process runs to be captured in a log file.
I pre-spawn a terminal that "tails" all log files so I can keep an eye on the progress of the updates of all machines.
So my requirements are:
1 Run ssh sessions on multiple computers in parallel.
2 Capture output of each session into a unique stream as the command is executing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use fabric to do some stuff remotely, you have first of all follow this structure to make a connection:

```
@task(hosts=["servername"])
def do_things(c):
     with connection(host=host, user=user,) as c:
        c.run("long-running-script-outputing-state-information-into-stdout.py")
```

This will output the whole output regardless what you are doing!

you have to use `with connection(host=host, user=user,) as c:` to ensure that everything you run will run within that connection context!

Comment: How does it solve the original problem? I need to spawn the remote server and keep waiting until it prints to stdout "initialization OK", then detach.